# Mac OS X screensaver fails to start with error: "Could not create patch from composition file"

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

We built a screensaver for Mac OS X called [Screensaver Ninja](https://ScreensaverNinja.com). I'm not the main developer, but I did work a bit on it. Now, the screensaver is not starting on my machine. It works fine for everybody else but I'm at a loss about what's causing it to not start in my machine.

In the console, I'm seeing these messages:

```
2015-12-21 10:08:23.426 ScreenSaverEngine[2756]: <QCScreenSaverView: 0x7fd638d4dcc0>: Could not create patch from composition file "/Users/pupeno/Library/Containers/com.carouselapps.ScreensaverNinja/Data/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver"
2015-12-21 10:08:23.441 ScreenSaverEngine[2756]: <QCScreenSaverView: 0x7fd638f69bb0>: Could not create patch from composition file "/Users/pupeno/Library/Containers/com.carouselapps.ScreensaverNinja/Data/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver"
2015-12-21 10:08:23.443 ScreenSaverEngine[2756]: <QCScreenSaverView: 0x7fd638c3d7b0>: Could not create patch from composition file "/Users/pupeno/Library/Containers/com.carouselapps.ScreensaverNinja/Data/Library/Screen Savers/Ninja.saver"
```

Any ideas what's going on here? We used mostly Swift to build it, with a bit of Objective-C [to handle a special case with cookies](https://screensaver.ninja/2015/12/04/browser-in-your-screensaver-is-square-peg-in-round-hole/).

In a computer where it works, there's no trace of that error. Another difference I notice is that if I go to folder where the Ninja.saver file is, `~/Library/Containers/com.carouselapps.ScreensaverNinja/Data/Library/Screen Ninja` and I double click on it, in my computer, I get this message:

[image: Ninja.saver is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash.]

while in computers in which it works, it offers to install it the way it normally does for .saver files.

**Update**: it started working almost by itself, so, now, I'm not sure what the problem was or how to solve it :(

Comment: This message appears (sometimes) when the product is not code signed with Apple id... To work around this  -> go to System Prefferences->Security & Privacy -> General Tab  and select radio button in "Allow apps downloaded from:" section "Anywhere"

Comment: Sometimes it happens when the .saver file was copied from Windows machine. In this case you should zip the file and then transfer to Windows and then transfer the zip to the mac

Comment: @user3351949 I really don't want to allow apps downloaded from anywhere. I have an Apple certificate, this app was downloaded from the app store after I signed and upload it.

Comment: @user3351949 it never touched a windows machine.

Comment: I just listed the possible causes, that I have encountered them personally that lead to the same. Have you tried to redownload the file ?